# Pin a DB in memory / Attach DB to a in memory DB

Tags: database, sqlite

I am using SQLLite with MS SQL Reporting Services via SQL Lite ODBC. The reports are quite complex and causes too many disk reads, sometimes taking over 5 minutes to generate a report. In order the improve performance, tried to do the following:

Restoring the database file (or its backup) into a in memory database and then ran the query

```
> .restore c:/mypath/a.db; 
> select * from mytable;
```

Works great command line, but ODBC tells me that I cannot execute these two commands at once.

Is there a way with SQLite ODBC that I can pin a SQLite DB In memory to overcome disk read issues?

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to optimize your queries?

Comment: I answered the question you asked. If you want to know how to speed up the queries that are executed on your DB, you should ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

`.restore` is not an SQL statement; it's implemented by the [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

There is no mechanism to pin an existing file-based database in memory. However, if it fits into memory, the OS will keep it in the file cache anyway.